# Iterator vs Iterable?

Tags: python, iterator

**(For python 3)**

In the python docs, [you can see](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) that the `list()` function takes an iterable.

In the python docs, [you can also see](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) that the `next()` funciton takes an iterator.

So I did this in IDLE:

```
>>> var = map(lambda x: x+5, [1,2,3])
>>> var
>>> next(v)
>>> list(v)
```

Which gives the output:

```
<map object at 0x000000000375F978>
6
[7,8]
```

Frankly, this isn't what I expected. Is a map object an iterator or an iterable? Is there even a difference? Clearly both the `list()` and `next()` functions work on the map object, whatever it is.

Why do they both work?

Comment: The python documentation says the result of `map` is always a list, which seems odd given your results.

Comment: [Not in python 3.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: You're right. In Python 3 it says "Return an iterator", so there you have your answer. I just did a google search and used the first result, didn't check the version.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In Python 3, most of these functions, `range`, `filter`, `map`, started returning iterators. It's much more memory efficient, (no more `xrange`)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

An iterator is an iterable, but an iterable is not necessarily an iterator.

An iterable is anything that has an `__iter__` method defined - e.g. lists and tuples, as well as iterators.

Iterators are a subset of iterables whose values cannot all be accessed at the same time, as they are not all stored in memory at once. These can be generated using functions like `map`, `filter` and `iter`, as well as functions using `yield`.

In your example, `map` returns an iterator, which is also an iterable, which is why both functions work with it. However, if we take a list for instance:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(lst)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> next(lst)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    next(lst)
TypeError: 'list' object is not an iterator
```

we can see that `next` complains, because the list, an iterable, is not an *iterator*.

Comment: "Iterators are a subset of iterables whose values cannot all be accessed at the same time, as they are not all stored in memory at once": this is completely incorrect. For example, if you are reading this before 2025, the values of python 3's `range(1000000000000000000)` iterable cannot fit in your laptop's memory. And yet, this iterable is *not* an iterator.

The correct definition is "Iterators are a subset of iterables that have `next` method."