# for loops in python require either iterable or iterator object.as such the following two for loops produce the same result

Tags: python

for loops in python require either iterable or iterator object.as such the following two for loops produce the same result.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
for i in iter(list):
    print(i)
print(end = "\n")
for i in list:
    print(i)
```

both the for loops prints out
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
my question is why we have these two forms ? why don't we use the second form only( directly iterating over the iterable than creating iterator from it and iterating )?

Comment: I have not used form #1 on lists in 20 years of Python programming. So, who exactly is "we"?

Comment: Don't name your lists `list`.

Comment: `iter` sometimes performs a useful role, but it is redundant here since `for` essentially calls `iter` anyways.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18809475/iterator-vs-iterable, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-iterator-iterable-and-iteration

Comment: thank you guys.  "Don't name your lists list" noted !!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `iter` for this type of use case

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
  
iter_arr = iter(arr)
  
print(next(iter_arr)) # 1
print(next(iter_arr)) # 2
print(next(iter_arr)) # 3
next(iter_arr)
print(next(iter_arr)) # 5
```

Answer (score 0):

iter() returns an iterable object which can be iterated one at time. Similar functionality can also be achieved by using yield keyword. This helps to reduce overhead of memory allocation.

Input:

```
res = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Using iter():

```
iter_obj = iter(res)

print(next(iter_obj))
print(next(iter_obj))
print(next(iter_obj))
print(next(iter_obj))
print(next(iter_obj))
```

Using Yield:

```
def f(res):
    for i in res:
        yield i

for i in f(res):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```